# Read value on Sheet1 from Sheet2 using vlookup

Tags: excel, if-statement, vlookup

I have the following on Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

Then on Sheet2, I have data. Following is the image.

[image: Sheet2]

I want to read the today's and tomorrow's for all the fruits from Sheet2 to Sheet1

I tried vlookup, but it didn't give me a right answer. It was confusing. I also tried to incorporate an if statement with the vlookup, but that made it more confusing.

Comment: Are you open to filling in column B with the fruits (so `B4` says "Apple", `B6` Banana, etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you data is consistent, you can use this formula `=IF(C$2="Today",INDEX(Sheet2!$D$3:$D$800,MATCH($B3,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$800,0)),INDEX(Sheet2!$D$3:$D$800,MATCH($B3,Sheet2!$B$3:$B$800,0)+1))` in cell `C3`. drag formula below whole table...

[image]

Comment: Oh, nice! I was trying to figure out how to do that without `B` totally filled in with the fruit on `Sheet2`.

Comment: that was actually also my first idea  :)

Comment: @Kreisimir L. My data is not going to be consistent. There could be fruits in sheet2 that I don't need so sheet1 won't have anything for that fruit

Comment: Situation you mentioned wont break this formula.

Comment: @KresimirL. What if I have around 200 rows? That's what I actually have.

Comment: Simply adjust formula to include all rows. you can try edited formula. Please mark as answered.

Comment: @KresimirL. Yea. But, that formula won't look clean with all that info in that.

Comment: @DD1 not sure what you mean by clean... based on you question, you received adequate answer. if you would like to receive more precise answer, then please ask a question with more details and meaning. take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more info.

Comment: @KresimirL. I agree with you. I didn't think about my original question before posting this. I thought the formula you or anyone else would give me will solve my problem. But, that's okay. Thanks! for your help. I appreciate it. I did accept your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is way to match with blank cells in between, but the best practice is to fill out those blanks to save your time and make the formula clean, moreover, it is very easy with this trick:

First, highlight the column (ie. `B1 to B6`), and then go `Home > Editing > Find & Select > Go To Special > Blanks > OK`, <kbd>=</kbd>, <kbd>upper arrow key</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  This way it will fill out all the blanks with the most available text in it.

[image]

Then you can perform this easy formula to do the subtotal task:

```
=SUMIFS($I$3:$I$13,$G$3:$G$13,$B3,$H$3:$H$13,C$2)
```

Please note that I put everything in the same tab to show you how this is being done.  You should change those ranges accordingly based on your data setup.  This way, you can have more data and different criteria be added on and still get the correct answer as I have shown you in the above screenshot.